# $\lVert x \rVert_1^k \leq C \left(|x_1|^k + \cdots + |x_n|^k \right)$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove that given $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a constant $C >0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$$\lVert x \rVert_1^k \leq C \left(|x_1|^k + \cdots +|x_n|^k \right)$$

where

$$\lVert x \rVert_1=|x_1|+ \cdots + |x_n|$$

Any ideas?

Comment: You can look up Minkowski's and Hölder's inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your problem is to find a constant, it is direct, my friend.
$\Vert x\Vert_1^k \le n^k \Vert x \Vert_{\infty}^k \le n^k( |x_1|^k+...+|x_n|^k)$